# how to start voltDB on runtime

Tags: php, database, voltdb

currently I start voltDB by terminal command I want to know that, is there any option for start voltDB on runtime by using  JSON interface or PHP .

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VoltDB can be started from the command line (directly or using a script), or by VoltDB Enterprise Manager.  Here are instructions on each of these methods:

- [Starting a VoltDB Database for the First Time](https://voltdb.com/docs/UsingVoltDB/RunStartDB.php) (command line)
- [Running VoltDB Example Applications](http://voltdb.com/docs/GettingStarted/SampleAppChap.php) (using a script)
- [VoltDB Management Guide](https://voltdb.com/docs/MgtGuide/) (using VoltDB Enterprise Manager)

The [VoltDB JSON HTTP interface](https://voltdb.com/docs/UsingVoltDB/ProgLangJson.php) uses an embedded HTTP server that (optionally) runs on each node in the cluster and is started along with the database.  It provides an HTTP interface to call stored procedures, system procedures, or Ad Hoc SQL statements via HTTP request, with responses in JSON-formatted text.  It can be used to interact with a running database, but not to start one.

Answer (score 0):

An example for Ubuntu Upstart for VoltDB 4.x Enterprise would be (update the paths and values accordingly):

```
cat << 'EOF' | sudo tee /etc/init/volt.conf
env VOLTDB_HEAPMAX=1024
start on runlevel [23]
stop on shutdown
chdir /home/ubuntu/data
exec /home/ubuntu/voltdb/bin/voltdb recover --deployment=prod.xml --host=db1 --license=license.xml
respawn
EOF
```

Note 1: `db1` must be in the `/etc/hosts` and it must point to the "leader" node (of your choosing) (you can also use an IP address directly)

Note 2: you first have to create/initialize the nodes by running the `create` command, also with the `--host=` parameter included.

Note 3: for the Community version, you have to perform `voltadmin pause` and `voltadmin save` before you restart the database process, and instead starting it with the `recover` option, you start it with `create` and then call `voltadmin restore` with the appropriate parameters. (I haven't done this yet, perhaps consider starting the DB in a paused state and then resume it after the snapshot is loaded.)